# How to get gauge with speed on video (GoPro telemetry imitation)

Tags: after-effects, premiere, video-editor

**INTRO:**

I am passionate for cycling and I want to make nice clips with my action camera. 
I have Xiaomi YI action camera and I put it on a bar of my bike to capture ride.

**PROBLEM:**

I want to add speed information to my video. 
I found that GoPro has built-in functionality for recording location information and video editor to put that data on video. And I want to achieve the same on my videos.

Here are some examples:
https://www.instagram.com/p/BReBvd2BI7X/
[image: gopro telemetry]

**INPUTS:**

I am programmer and I can create mobile app that will record location information during my ride.
Let's say I have information in any format needed, e.g. CSV (comma separated values):

```
Timestamp,Speed
12:10:01,30
12:10:02,32
12:10:03,33
```

I want to have gauge on my video that will show my speed. As I guess, real challenge is to make it consume my data.
I am familiar with Adobe Premiere Pro, but can also dive deep in After Effects it this will help me.

Comment: Try [Dashware](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18928/1871).

Comment: @Mulvya thank you, I checked it, looks realistic and easy.
This can be considered as answer.

Comment: You could also do it with adobe extendscript scripting and after effects.